# QGtk style not display the progressbar in the QTreeView

Tags: c++, linux, qt, gtk

I ported my app to the Ubuntu platform, built my project with Cmake build system, and added dependence of GTK library (not linking without). After I run my program but the Delegate for `QtreeView` does not display the progressbar, when my program running messages like that appear in debug output:

```
Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_style_get: assertion `GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)'
```

what's wrong and why do I get this messages? If I change `QGtkStyle` to another style, the app works properly.